# Setting column width in html table doesn't display scrollbar

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create an HTML table where the column widths are changed dynamically, and in case the table width becomes larger than the container, a horizontal scrollbar appears.

However, I can't seem to get this to work - when I set the container width, it acts as an upper bound for the table and even though I set a column's width explicitly (either using CSS or Jquery) the table refuses to display the correct width. Even when I set "overflow: scroll", the scrollbar never becomes active.

The table width should also decrease when the column widths become smaller, which is why I can't use table width = 100%.

***Note***: I know this issue can be bypassed if I explicitly set the table width (e.g. table width=500px) every time a column width changes. I am hoping there is a more elegant solution...

Here is the code:

**JFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/NdY22/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="a">th 1</th>
            <th>th 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td 1</td>
            <td>td 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
}


.container{
    border: 1px solid lightsteelblue;
    width: 300px; 
    overflow: auto;                
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
   $('.a').width(500);
});
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you are after scrollbars in table then you can simple do that by using `display: block` on `.a` class:

```
.a {
    width: 400px;
    display:block;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NdY22/26/)

Comment: It's an interesting answer but changing the cell elements to block messes up the table display - see [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/NdY22/36/)

Comment: Is this better? http://jsfiddle.net/NdY22/39/. Applying class to th messes it up, I wrapped the element in span instead.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
<div STYLE=" height: 100px; width: 100px; font-size: 12px; overflow: auto;">
    <table bgcolor="green">
       <tr><td bgcolor="blue">testing </td></tr>
       <tr><td>free php scripts;/td></tr>
       <tr><td bgcolor="blue">free php scripts</td></tr>
       <tr><td>free php scripts</td></tr>
       <tr><td bgcolor="blue">free php scripts</td></tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

[see reference](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/css/scrollable-table.php)

Comment: This isn't what I was asking..I'm not trying to place scrollbars inside individual cells, but on the table as a whole.

Comment: ohh, actually i was too hurry and misunderstood. Now, see my edited answer.